# Bscscan api wrong check verified contract result

Tags: bscscan

This contract here :

https://bscscan.com/address/0xfbD2aa7efA2B46Ce3c58D7ab0D92C176c71499C0

Is verified obviously, when making an api call tk check if it is verified or not, this is the returned result:

`{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":[{"SourceCode":"","ABI":"Contract source code not verified","ContractName":"","CompilerVersion":"","OptimizationUsed":"","Runs":"","ConstructorArguments":"","EVMVersion":"Default","Library":"","LicenseType":"Unknown","Proxy":"0","Implementation":"","SwarmSource":""}]}`

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The contract is not verified.

https://bscscan.com/address/0xfbD2aa7efA2B46Ce3c58D7ab0D92C176c71499C0#code

> **Similar Match Source Code**
> Note: This contract matches the deployed ByteCode of the Source Code for Contract 0xbc569c7bc7e09b313e1124a92b9b95408a725b59

Bscscan finds another verified contract by ByteCode, but unfortunately doesn't provide this information via API.